# How to create 2D map in unity using single image?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have to create 2D map in unity using single image. So, i have one .png file with 5 different pieces out of which I have to create a map & i am not allowed to crop the image. So, how do create this map using only one image.

I am bit new to unity, i tried searching but didn't find exactly what i am looking for. Also tried, tilemap using Pallet but couldn't figure out how to extract only one portion of the image.

Comment: Yes, i want to use 5 different sprites from single image to create a map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create various Sprites from the given texture on the fly in code.

You can define which part of a given `Texture2D` shall be used for the Sprite using [`Sprite.Create`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html) providing the [`rect`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rect.html) in pixel coordinates of the given image. Remember however that in unity texture coordinates start **bottom left**.

Example use the given pixel coordinate snippet of a texture for the attached `UI.Image` component:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Image))]
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    // your texture e.g. from a public field via the inspector
    public Texture2D texture;

    // define which pixel coordinates to use for this sprite also via the inspector
    public Rect pixelCoordinates;

    private void Start()
    {
        var newSprite = Sprite.Create(texture, pixelCoordinates, Vector2.one / 2f);

        GetComponent<Image>().sprite = newSprite;
    }

    // called everytime something is changed in the Inspector
    private void OnValidate()
    {
        if (!texture)
        {
            pixelCoordinates = new Rect();
            return;
        }

        // reset to valid rect values
        pixelCoordinates.x = Mathf.Clamp(pixelCoordinates.x, 0, texture.width);
        pixelCoordinates.y = Mathf.Clamp(pixelCoordinates.y, 0, texture.height);
        pixelCoordinates.width = Mathf.Clamp(pixelCoordinates.width, 0, pixelCoordinates.x + texture.width);
        pixelCoordinates.height = Mathf.Clamp(pixelCoordinates.height, 0, pixelCoordinates.y + texture.height);
    }
}
```

---

Or you get make a kind of manager class for generating all needed sprites once e.g. in a list like

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    // your texture e.g. from a public field via the inspector
    public Texture2D texture;

    // define which pixel coordinates to use for this sprite also via the inspector
    public List<Rect> pixelCoordinates = new List<Rect>();

    // OUTPUT
    public List<Sprite> resultSprites = new List<Sprite>();

    private void Start()
    {
        foreach(var coordinates in pixelCoordinates)
        {
            var newSprite = Sprite.Create(texture, coordinates, Vector2.one / 2f);

            resultSprites.Add(newSprite);
        }
    }

    // called everytime something is changed in the Inspector
    private void OnValidate()
    {
        if (!texture)
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < pixelCoordinates.Count; i++)
            {
                pixelCoordinates[i] = new Rect();
            }
            return;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < pixelCoordinates.Count; i++)
        {
            // reset to valid rect values
            var rect = pixelCoordinates[i];

            rect.x = Mathf.Clamp(pixelCoordinates[i].x, 0, texture.width);
            rect.y = Mathf.Clamp(pixelCoordinates[i].y, 0, texture.height);
            rect.width = Mathf.Clamp(pixelCoordinates[i].width, 0, pixelCoordinates[i].x + texture.width);
            rect.height = Mathf.Clamp(pixelCoordinates[i].height, 0, pixelCoordinates[i].y + texture.height);

            pixelCoordinates[i] = rect;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Example:

I have 4 `Image` instances and configured them so the `pixelCoordinate`s are:

- imageBottomLeft: `X=0, Y=0, W=100, H=100`
- imageTopLeft: `X=0, Y=100, W=100, H=100`
- imageBottomRight: `X=100, Y=0, W=100, H=100`
- imageTopRight: `X=100, Y=100, W=100, H=100`

The texture I used is `386 x 395` so I'm not using all of it here (just added the frames the Sprites are going to use)

[image]

so when hitting Play the following sprites are created:

[image]

Comment: Okay, so variable texture is my image from where i will be extracting particular piece of image and storing it in pixelCoordinates, right ?
Just like croping an image, then i can store these coordinates in an array of Vector2 type to create a bitmap.

I'll let you know how it goes , Thank you, in advance.

Comment: it is similar to a croping on runtime yes. These coordinates already can be directly stored in the `Rect` field ... no need for `Vector2` .. you could also make a `List<Rect>` for multiple Sprites yes

Comment: Silly question :p but where do i attach the script ?

Comment: In my example case on a `GameObject` with an `Image` attached next to it ;) I just added a second example of a manager class for genrating multiple sprites depending on different coordinate setups

Comment: It is throwing an error in OnValidate function, saying 
Cannot assign to 'coordinates' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable' (CS1656)

Comment: yes sorry, this happens when you code things on your smartphone ^^ it has to be `for` loops instead ;)

Comment: in this case it says, 
Cannot modify the return value of 'List<Rect>.this[int]' because it is not a variable

Comment: :D .. ok now it should do it ^^

Comment: Why not just use "multiple" as sprite mode on import and use the SpriteEditor? Do you really need to do that programatically @Marx, it kinda sounds like reinventing the wheel? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpriteEditor.html

Comment: Yeah @yes ik how stupid it sounds, but have to do it. My primary objective is to create pacman in unity ( without using colliders, rigibodies , raycasts or character controll , also nav mesh is not allowed ) :p